# iPhone Playing a sound clip while recording a video using UIImagePickerController ... possible?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, audio

I'm using openAL to play sounds. I have a view controller that lets users upload a video. I want to give them a 1 minute warning sound so that they know to wrap things up. I tried using a call to `SoundEngine_StartEffect(warningSound);` but it just doesn't play anything. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: Wild guess: put the call on a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set mix with others?

```
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 1; 
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(UInt32), &doSetProperty);
```

It is in most cases a "must have", when trying to record and play at the same time.